# Include one target's include directories in another target

Tags: cmake

How can I include `target1`'s include directories (made by `target_include_directories(target1 t1/include)`) into `target2`?

I know only one way, which is to create a variable and `set()` include directories in it, and then reuse the variable for another target. But this looks too non-flexible, and I think CMake must have an much easier way.
My targets are shared libraries.

Comment: Why not just link against `target1`?

Comment: @StephenNewell sorry, info about linkage was misleading because i use dynamic linkage. Does cmake populates include dirs of statically linked target? (When you pass target name as argument to target_link_libraries)

Comment: Assuming your target has `INTERFACE` include directories (I'm guessing it does based on your proposed solution), then linking against the library will automatically apply those directories.  This only works if the library is a cmake target, but that sounds like the case with your problem.

Comment: @StephenNewell thanks for the answer, it will be useful for future projects, but at the current project I use `dll`'s to glue all parts of my project and we cannot link dynamic libraries statically - so I need include dirs explicitly. That generator expression looks like working for both PUBLIC and INTERFACE visibility, but i don't know how can i print its output into console

Comment: @Herrgott You can use [`get_target_property()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_target_property.html) to put the property into a variable. Then, print the variable using `message()`.

Comment: @squareskittles it doesn't work for generator expression. It prints expression itself, not result

Comment: I'm not sure why a generator expression is necessary. You could just do `get_target_property(MY_INTERFACE_DIRS target1 INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)`.

Comment: @squareskittles It doubles lines of code because `get_target_property` doesn't return result it sets result into variable instead. I thought there was a way to just pass target name and cmake picked up all include dirs automatically

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify, I was only suggesting to use `get_target_property()` if you wanted to *print* the property to the console. Not for using it in another target...

Answer (score 9):

`"$<TARGET_PROPERTY:TargetName,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>"`
is what I looked for

using like that:

```
target_include_directories(MyTarget
    PRIVATE
    "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:OtherTarget,INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES>"
)
```

it allows me to include `PUBLIC` and `INTERFACE` include directories of target `OtherTarget` into `MyTarget`

Comment: I'm not familiar with this syntax. It doesn't look like a typical variable. Can you provide more context?

Comment: It's cmake [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) syntax.